# Segmentation fault core dump

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ScanArray (int* , int*);
int Pair (int* , int);

int main () {

        int a [15] , n;

        ScanArray (a , &n);

//      printf("\nHello World !!!\n");

        if(Pair(a , n) == 0)
                printf("The array fulfills the requirements");
        else
                printf("The array does not fulfills the requirements");

        return 0;
}

void ScanArray (int *a , int *n) {

        int i , f = 0;


        do {
        printf("Enter the number of integers : ");
        scanf("%d",n);

        if (*n > 15)
                printf("Enter number bellow 15 \n");
        else
                f=1;
        } while(f == 0);

        printf("Enter the %d integers : ",*n);
        for (i = 0 ; i < *n ; i++)
                scanf("%d",a+i);

}

int Pair (int *a , int n) {

        if (n <= 1)
                return 0;
        else
                if (*a-*(a+1) != 1 && *a-*(a+1) != -1)
                        return 1;
                else
                        return Pair(a++ , n--);

}
```

don't know why it's not working.

Segmentation fault (core dump).

Comment: Where does it crash? Have you tried a debugger like gdb?

Comment: YOu are getting a stack overflow in Pair(), which never exits, and is recursive.

Comment: This is really a "give a man a fish / teach a man to fish" moments. I'm sure this will not be the last core dump you will ever get.  Try compiling your program with debug enabled (-g under gcc), run it, and load the core into gdb.  There should be plenty of gdb tutorials on the interwebs.

Comment: you should at least accept the correct answer

Answer (score 4):

```
else
    return Pair(a++ , n--);
```

Using postfix increment and decrement operators will result in the recursive call processing the same values. You should either use prefix operators, or even better, just add and subtract 1.

```
else
    return Pair(a + 1 , n - 1);
```

I say that's better because it's misleading to think modifying the values matters; the key to recursion is that the recursive calls will have their own copies of `a` and `n`, so modifying them in a parent has no effect on the children.